# ¿Como usar EDGAR en R?

Tags: r, web

Tengo una duda con el uso del paquete EDGAR, ya que no se usarlo bien.

```
library(edgar)    
output_filings <- getFilings(cik.no = c(1000180, 38079), c('10-K','10-Q'),2006, quarter = c(1, 2, 3))
```

Después te pregunta si deseas descargar los archivos, es ahí donde escribo `y` genera mi variable `output_filings` donde dice que la descarga ha sido un éxito,  a partir de este punto no se que puedo hacer para visualizar los archivos 10-Q y 10-K, para poder procesarlos.

Si conocen otro método para poder esta información seria de mucha ayuda.
Traté con `getfinancials` del paquete `quantmod` pero esta función ya no sirve.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Leyendo el [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/edgar/edgar.pdf) muy por arriba, lo que entiendo es que este paquete sirve básicamente para descargar información que se guarda localmente en distintas carpetas. Por ejemplo, en el caso de `getFilings()`:

> getFilings function takes CIKs, form type, filing year, and quarter of
> the filing as input. **It creates new directory "Edgar filings_full
> text" to store all downloaded filings**. All the filings will be stored
> in the current working directory. Keep the same current working
> directory for further process

simplemente descarga la información solicitada en carpeta de trabajo actual:

```
file.path(getwd(),'Edgar filings_full tex')
```

Dentro de ella, habrá subcarpetas para cada `form.type` y `cik.no`. La información retornada es simplemente un `data.frame` de resumen, pero no la información en sí, que deberás buscarla en la carpeta mencionada.